# How to point a domain to git through Route53

Tags: amazon-route53

I am moving all my sites over to my git account for hosting.  I don't have a whole lot of experience with git or route53 and can't seem to find many answers on this.  I updated my registrar with the route53 nameservers and created a CNAME on my github.  Do I put the git IP's under the SOA section on Route53 for this domain?

I'm sure this has been covered before but I didn't see any results when doing a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on the Route53 forum.  Most of the time you can route a domain through your registrar but in this case I was using a .la extension which doesn't have this capability.

Here is your answer:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=526698&#526698